# CSS spacing issues in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular5, angular6

We just recently upgraded to Angular 6 from Angular 5 and noticed the buttons/icons, etc has no spacing between them.

We would like to restore the spaces between the buttons, etc.
I have managed to reproduce the issues below.
As you can see in the example with Angular 5, There are spaces between the buttons inside and outside of angular app.

But

Angular 6 removed the spacing between the buttons inside the angular app.

Any idea?

**Angular 5 example** (I want this behaviour)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-example-kyu8ud?file=index.html

**Angular 6 example** (With issues described above)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vyfwih?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: because in angular 5 you use bootstrap and in angular 6 no!!!

Comment: I did not include the bootstrap package

Comment: in your project??

Comment: Just define a global style with ```margin: 4px;``` shortcut

Comment: I like to find out why instead of fixing all the buttons individually. Too much testing and time involved

Comment: when I remove bootstrap from angular 5 it look exactly like angular6... I guess it about import bootstrap to angular 6

Comment: I don’t think that is the case. I tried including bootstrap in 6 too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Angular 6 the [**`preserveWhitespaces`**](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#preserveWhitespaces) compiler option is set to `false`. That is why you observe that behavior. You can change this in your `tsconfig` file:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "preserveWhitespaces": true
}
```

Essentially it is the difference between:

```
<button>Test1</button> <-- whitespace here
<button>Test2</button>
```

and

```
<button>Test1</button><button>Test2</button> <-- no whitespace
```

[**Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-example-nffyjx?file=app/app.component.html) is your Angular 5 example with no whitespace, you will see it is now the same as the Angular 6 version.

Comment: Strangely enough I can't update the examples I provided. There is no tsconfig

Comment: Yeah, [stackblitz does not have support](https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/220) for exposing `tsconfig` yet :(

Comment: Will confirm it once I get hold of the code tomorrow :)

Comment: For my case, we need to update `tsconfig.app.json` and manually defining in `main.ts` for ng serve to work too

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are having bootstrap in Angular 5 Example. Please look into the screenshot of your dependencies. Bootstrap is there :).

[Screenshot of list of Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuVo1.png)

You just need to think, when you added the bootstrap as the dependency.

Comment: No, the [same behavior](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-example-nffyjx?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) is exhibited without bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

please use this is your file

platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule, { preserveWhitespaces: true})

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked (combining answers in this post) and got my whitespacing back by adding):

```
,
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "preserveWhitespaces": true
}
```

to **tsconfig.app.json**

and indeed also add it to **main.ts** by adding it to platformBrowserDynamic like this:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, { preserveWhitespaces: true})
```

After that: ng serve again to load the new changes